# Airflow webserver, the Last run time and the actual run time is not the same

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-2.x, airflow-webserver

Here is the DAGs summary
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xND1k.png)

But if I click at the Last Run time, click at the red box, it directed me to DAG page.
and the time is hour+1, even the time zone is the same.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eoAyQ.png)

Also at log, its hour+1 from the home page.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjvCr.png)

additional source.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFz0c.png)

Thanks,

I want to know the cause, is that a bug or I misunderstood the concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is not the same. The last run time refer to the ***data interval start*** in the DAG, whereas the timestamp in the second and third image refer to the ***data interval end*** in the DAG.

Comment: So, what is the concept of data interval ? it's not a bug right?

Comment: Each DAG run in Airflow has an assigned “data interval” that represents the time range it operates in. For a DAG scheduled with @daily, for example, each of its data intervals would start each day at midnight (00:00) and end at midnight (24:00).

Ref: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/dag-run.html#data-interval

Comment: Yes, it's not a bug.